# Find seventh term of the evaluation of $(2a+b^2)^8$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

I need to find the seventh term of 
$(2a+b^2)^8$ 
But, at this moment, the only way to solve this I can make up is to distribute the brackets.. 
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

From the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) we have

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

Then, evaluate term $7$ when $n=8$, $x=2a$, and $y=b^2$.

Comment: And I love chess too!  1) e4 ...

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Using the binomial theorem, we can expand $(a+b)^8$ to be

${8 \choose 0}a^8 + {8 \choose 1}a^7b + {8 \choose 2}a^6b^2 + {8 \choose 3}a^5b^3 + {8 \choose 4}a^4b^4 + {8 \choose 5}a^3b^5 + {8 \choose 6}a^2b^6+{8 \choose 7}ab^7 + {8 \choose 8}b^8$

From this we get the seventh term to be ${8 \choose 6}a^2b^6$ or $28a^2b^6$.

Note that in the above expansion, we used a and b. To fit your formula of $(2a + b^2)^8$ we simply replace a and b for the answer of ${8 \choose 6}(2a)^2(b^2)^6$ or $7168a^2b^{12}$.